what causes the lack of output voltage in a circuit with a SCR?
In this circuit, when the main switch is on, there is almost no output voltage (either DC or AC). I started to troubleshoot this circuit by desoldering and checking two components outside the circuit: 1. the yellow X2 100nF capacitor and 2. the green VDR (connected in parallel between Line and Neutral). Both of them are OK.
How the supply voltage of the MCU should be checked?
(The first two pictures show two sides of one board; the last two pictures show two sides of the other board.)



1: 

The component IF1 seams to have a burned hole. Can you confirm this, please?

You did check the fuse if it is blown or not?

The fuse in IF1 is OK, because I measured the voltage after it, and it was 220VAC. Also, in continuity test, it beeped.

Can you include a picture of the the other PCB? This one does not have the controlling element, usually a TRIAC. You will find that the problem is on the other board.

@Edin Fifić. Sorry for the delay. I included pictures of the both sides of the other PCB.

@SAA Vcc should be the positive side of the MCU supply voltage. MB could be the negative side. The C5 could be the capacitor across the supply rails of the MCU. I am sorry I can't help you much further, it takes too much time and effort to analyze it only from the pictures. It takes a lot of figuring out even if it were in my hands, though it would be much faster and easier.

Not the answer.
Looks like there is some sort of temperature control (+/-).
Usually you'd expect to find a TRIAC on the board for voltage control, which I don't see here. This is like a part of the full circuit.
Knowing the model of the heater would help.

There is another board that contains a SCR (TYN612) and a MCU (113TC 5252). If by "the model of the heater", you mean codes, I can't see the code because the heater has a back cover. But if you mean its physical characteristics, tell me to upload its pictures.

There is at least one more PCB in that device, but you have not shown it in your pictures.
My guess is that it includes an MCU and a TRIAC.
The PCB you're showing is responsible for bringing in the main power, fusing it, removing noise, preventing overvoltage, supplying the actual control circuitry consisting of probably an MCU and a TRIAC, and for sending your commands through the buttons to the MCU or a similar control circuit.
On the other board you should check if the TRIAC or the MCU is bad.
Typically the TRIAC goes bad in this type of circuits.

You are right; there is another board that contains a SCR (TYN612) and a MCU (113TC 5252). I know how to test a SCR. Can you explain how to check if the MCU is bad?

@SAA You should check if the MCU is getting its supply voltage. It might be using 3.3V or 5V. Then check if it outputs a positive voltage to the SCR gate when it's supposed to turn it on. But do these checks with an external power supply, or be VERY careful if plugging it into the outlet while testing! Check if those 4 diodes near the heater are good. Though they fail rarely, it is still possible. My guess is that the heater is either using half of the AC cycles, or that the diodes are forming a rectifier bridge through which the AC passes and is presented to the SCR as DC to simplify control.
